# Entity splitting when value is a list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 tables which stores data for my MVC3 program ( I made sample tables to illustrate).

[image]

I'm using Entity Framework but don't know how to connect those tables so I will get something like this:

```
    public class TableABC
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public List<string> Colours { get; set; }

    public List<string> Pets { get; set; }
}
```

I found that this is called "Entity splitting" and I need to map those table, but completely dont know how to start.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: are you using code first or database first?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't map table to primitive type. Each entity should have id. So, you should have some `Colour` entity with id and value. And TableABC should contain list of Colours instead of list of strings. Same for pets

Comment: I use DbContext, so I think is a code first, but correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't map primitive type to table, so instead of string lists you should another entities:

```
public class TableABC
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Colour> Colours { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
}

public class Colour
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Pet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here are mappings (override OnModelCreating method of your custom DbContext to provide mappings):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TableABC>().Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("name");
modelBuilder.Entity<TableABC>().Property(t=>t.Surname).HasColumnName("surname");
modelBuilder.Entity<TableABC>()
    .HasMany(t => t.Colours).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<TableABC>()
    .HasMany(t => t.Pets).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(p => p.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<Colour>().Property(c => c.Value).HasColumnName("colours");
modelBuilder.Entity<Colour>().HasKey(c => new { c.Id, c.Value });
modelBuilder.Entity<Pet>().Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnName("pets");
modelBuilder.Entity<Pet>().HasKey(c => new { c.Id, c.Name });
```

Keep in mind that I used composite keys for colours and pets and it should be unique for all records.